# Owl carousel rtl nav arrows issue

Tags: jquery, css, owl-carousel

I'm using owl carousel rtl slides coming from the opposite direction, in addition, I added nav for showing owl-next, owl-prev arrows.
I've noticed that there is an issue with owl-next, owl-prev arrows, For Example, if click on owl-next it's showing the previous slide, the same thing when with owl-prev when I click on it it's showing the next slide.
Is there any solution to solve it?

```js
    $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
      animateOut: 'fadeOut',
      items:1,
      loop:true,
      autoplay:true,
      autoplayHoverPause:false,
      rtl:true,
      mouseDrag: false,
      touchDrag: false,
      nav:true,
    navText: ['<span class="fas fa-chevron-left fa-2x"></span>','<span class="fas fa-chevron-right fa-2x"></span>'],
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is a text direction issue. Try to add `direction: rtl;` declaration to `owl-stage-outer` class.

Comment: There is no class in that name

Comment: Try to look in the DOM. You can also find the class in `owl.carousel.min.css` file